# Storing Passport Numbers in a database

Tags: best-practices, encryption, storage

We're developing a travel/tourist application for a tours company who want to be able to input traveler information into an online database.

Is there any security best practice for storing passport numbers in a database? Should it be encrypted?

Comment: Would you say passport numbers are more or less sensitive than, say, credit card numbers or passwords?

Comment: also @NickChammas passport numbers and SSN?

Comment: Relevant legal info http://searchsecurity.techtarget.com/answer/Personally-identifiable-information-guidelines-for-US-passport-numbers

Comment: @jcolebrand - Another valid comparison.  Just leading the OP to see that passport numbers should be treated with the same security and gravity as these other pieces of information.

Comment: I wonder why is it even necessary for a tour company to store the passport numbers.

Answer (score 4):

Passport numbers should definitely be encrypted in the database.  You should investigate the legality of collecting and storing this information before proceeding.

Comment: Very good point about the legal requirements.

Answer (score 1):

As datagod points there's a legality component towards the practice of storing sensitive information such as a passport number. Where I live an active enforce of UK law [Data protection act](http://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/1998/29/contents) is the standard practice. 
But in other places like Chile is totally legal to store passport number which is the same as the ID (RUN), some [websites](http://datos.24x7.cl/) even offer the possibility to retrieve a Passport/ID No by providing a full name.

So in a way I guess it would be better to search for local legislation in the subject.